# ListBox scrollbar always visible in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, listbox

I am using a listbox that-- only in Chrome-- always has its vertical scrollbar visible regardless of how many items are in it.  In all other browsers, when the number of rows in the listbox equals or exceeds the number of items, the scrollbar automatically hides itself.

Does anybody know how to get that result in Chrome?

Comment: Adding a style that says: `overflow-y: auto;` doesn't help?

Comment: try to put a style that targets the first child of the listbox control, and give it a background color. See if it goes way down to the bottom of the outer border. If it does there is an internal wrapper for the items that maybe renders too big inside the listbox, and it causes to always have the scrollbar (only in chrome). And try fiixng overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: This appears to just be a flaw with the Chrome browser.  Not a whole lot you can do really other than just make sure the page still functions and just suffer with the minor display glitch.

Comment: @Marino, I appreciate your help.  I tried overflow-y:hidden and it did not change anything, which I found strange.  Is there no other way to target the internal wrapper you're referring to?

Comment: Can you please show us some code? I didn't know HTML had a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

To hide this vertical scrollbar (and the horizontal scrollbar if that appears too), you need to use the CSS overflow property, with a value of hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using auto instead? 
for example:

```
#listbox
{
    overflow: auto
}
```